# Read  file and open the content with txt file -Header is not displayed properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Below is my code ,in that i am reading a content in a file then i can show and download the content in a txt file .but when i open the txt file the header is looks like filename.txt[1] .i want filename anly as a header.i dont know what it [1] means.

```
public FileResult Download(string id)
    {
        int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        LoadFileInfoCache();
        var fileDetails = from ff in _currentFileDetails
                          where ff.FileId == rowId
                          select new
                          {
                              name = ff.FileName,
                              location = ff.FileLocation
                          };
        var fileDetailsList = fileDetails.ToList();
        string fileLocation = fileDetailsList[0].location;
        string fileName = fileDetailsList[0].name + ".txt";
        string contentType = "application/txt";
        var file = System.IO.File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        var stream = (Stream)(file);

        return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

can anyone please help ,where went wrong in my code.

Comment: What is the problem exactly. Have a logic error in the code, such as

Answer (score 1):

The '[1]' appears because the client machine already has a file with the same name. The SO puts a [1] in front of it to avoid conflict or overwriting. This is not a error, this is the default behavior and cannot be changed. However the user who's dowloading the file can change the file name if he want to.